# How to orchestrate automatic multiple (non-)ros component based system start?

Tags: ros, roslaunch, bash, best-practices

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Problem/Scenario**

I am trying implement a way to automatically bootstrap/start a complex system
that uses diverse *ros* and *non-ros* components. My web-search lead me to
*roslaunch*, which seems to be most suitable for this task (is it?).
However, I encountered several problems during the creation of a preliminary
launchfile and general system setup. My goal is to compare the capabilities
of ROS with those of a new framework created within the scope of my current
research.

**My question:**

Is there a best practice or recommended approach to realise such a
system startup when using mixed ros and non-ros components? Or does
this scenario not really fit well with the ROS framework and should be
implemented independently?

**Exemplary encountered issues:**

1. Some components require to access log files of other components
   during run time (e.g. live plotting of non-ros components). I found
   out that there is a *run_id*
   in the log folder but there seems to be no way to find out what the current roslaunch *run_id* is (e.g. via env variables).
2. Organisation/Orchestration of components (some need to run
   **after** others have finished or only under certain circumstances)
   seems to be impossible with using just roslaunch. Further, using the
   *if* tag also seems impossible as there is no way to assess if and
   *when* a component is running. From what I gathered, heavy
   shell/script hacks need to be done.

   Please refer to:

   wiki.ros.org/roslaunch
   Proposed Features problem

   - "Dependencies: "launch prog X once Y is running""
   - "Allow binaries that are not in ros packages to be roslaunched"

   wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML
   Evaluation Order problem:

   - "Tags are evaluated serially and the last setting wins."
3. Thus, re-use seems to be unfeasible, because scripts and hacks will
   lead into a "black hole" and never allow me to reuse any of the scripts
   without manually adjusting component specific sleeps or waits.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/123411/how-to-orchestrate-automatic-multiple-(non-)ros-component-based-system-start?/) by [qsalber](https://answers.ros.org/users/11356/qsalber/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-01-28

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are using Ubuntu, [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) is one tool for handling problems like yours.

Many ROS robots use something like the [ros_upstart](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_upstart) package.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2014-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2